How Vertex AI rate limits are calculated on GCP?
I'm planning to use Google Cloud Platform's Vertex AI for a few projects. So, I was looking through the documentation in the section on rate limits and I came across this:

https://cloud.google.com/vertex-ai/generative-ai/docs/quotas
But I haven't found any information anywhere about the algorithm that sets these limits.
That is, I have two scenarios in my mind:

First scenario: The limits are at fixed times. For example, between
08:00:00 AM and 08:00:59 AM there are 4 million tokens available and
at 08:01:00 AM the tokens are reset.
Second scenario: The limits move as requests are made.

Or maybe it's different from the scenarios outlined.
I would appreciate if someone could explain to me how Google calculates it, or if there is a section of the documentation where I can find this since I haven't seen it.

I think you would have better luck asking here https://discuss.ai.google.dev/

generate_content_input_tokens_per_minute_per_base_model is a Google Cloud Metrics under aiplatform. These are the list of metrics related to generate_content_input_tokens_per_minute_per_base_model:

quota/generate_content_input_tokens_per_minute_per_base_model/exceeded - Number of attempts to exceed the limit on quota metric aiplatform.googleapis.com/generate_content_input_tokens_per_minute_per_base_model. After sampling, data is not visible for up to 150 seconds.

quota/generate_content_input_tokens_per_minute_per_base_model/limit - Current limit on quota metric aiplatform.googleapis.com/generate_content_input_tokens_per_minute_per_base_model. Sampled every 60 seconds. After sampling, data is not visible for up to 150 seconds.

quota/generate_content_input_tokens_per_minute_per_base_model/usage - Current usage on quota metric aiplatform.googleapis.com/generate_content_input_tokens_per_minute_per_base_model. After sampling, data is not visible for up to 150 seconds.



Thank you very much for your reply, however I don't understand how this can help me identify the algorithm that Google uses for the rate limit. Still, thank you:)
